# Copy and Paste in First Empty Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet of products, which are in particular fonts and backgrounds.

After I perform the find function (CLTR-F), I want to click a macro button which will copy my selection, and paste it into the first available cell in Row N starting with the second row ("N2") and ending with the 12th row ("N12").

I have more data in N, for example in N13 and N14, so I cannot simply count the rows occupied and add one. I want this process to exit once the first cell has been pasted into.

The goal is that once the value is pasted, the process ends. But if the value is not pasted, it will go onto the next available cell and paste, and end, and so on if the cells are occupied until it is pasted in the first empty cell.

What I have pastes into both N2 and N3, if N2 is not occupied.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteFirstEmptyCell()
    
    'Copy the selection
    Selection.Copy
    
    'Test for N2
    If IsEmpty(Range("N2")) = True Then
        Selection.Copy Range("N2")
    End If
    
    'Test for N3
    If IsEmpty(Range("N2")) = True Then
        Selection.Copy Range("N3")
    
    'Test For N4-N12 etc. etc. 
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Most simply use the vba function `Range("N2").End(XLDown)` to move the cursor to the first empty cell downward.

Comment: Your way didn't work. I found out how to do it.

Comment: After reading your code, I get a better understanding of Your problem. However the `End` function is suitable for moving to the first empty cell in a column or row. If You have multiple columns, you have to check every column, that is clear.
I am glad, You found an answer.

Comment: For some reason when I used your code my sheet kept skipping all the way to "N15" when I used the End(XLdown) function from "N2" Even when the column was completely empty without formatting and the cells answering yes to the IsEmpty function. I am not quite sure why. I am sure in most cases that End function would work and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I created variables and added them to a final variable to decide the range.

```vb
Sub Copy()

'Copy the selection
Selection.Copy

'Create variables
Dim intN2 As Integer
Dim intN3 As Integer
Dim intN4 As Integer
Dim intN5 As Integer
Dim intN6 As Integer
Dim intN7 As Integer
Dim intN8 As Integer
Dim intN9 As Integer
Dim intN10 As Integer
Dim intN11 As Integer
Dim intN12 As Integer
Dim finalint As Integer

'Create If Then statements to increaes finalint
'For N2
If IsEmpty(Range("N2")) = True Then
    intN2 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N2")) = False Then
    intN2 = 1
End If

'For N3
If IsEmpty(Range("N3")) = True Then
    intN3 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N3")) = False Then
    intN3 = 1
End If

'For N4
If IsEmpty(Range("N4")) = True Then
    intN4 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N4")) = False Then
    intN4 = 1
End If

'For N5
If IsEmpty(Range("N5")) = True Then
    intN5 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N5")) = False Then
    intN5 = 1
End If

'For N6
If IsEmpty(Range("N6")) = True Then
    intN6 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N6")) = False Then
    intN6 = 1
End If

'For N7
If IsEmpty(Range("N7")) = True Then
    intN7 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N7")) = False Then
    intN7 = 1
End If

'For N8
If IsEmpty(Range("N8")) = True Then
    intN8 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N8")) = False Then
    intN8 = 1
End If

'For N9
If IsEmpty(Range("N9")) = True Then
    intN9 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N9")) = False Then
    intN9 = 1
End If

'For N10
If IsEmpty(Range("N10")) = True Then
    intN10 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N10")) = False Then
    intN10 = 1
End If

'For N11
If IsEmpty(Range("N11")) = True Then
    intN11 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N11")) = False Then
    intN11 = 1
End If

'For N12
If IsEmpty(Range("N12")) = True Then
    intN12 = 0
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("N12")) = False Then
    intN12 = 1
End If

'Make finalint the total of all other integers
finalint = intN2 + intN3 + intN4 + intN5 + intN6 + intN7 + intN8 + intN9 + intN10 + intN11 + intN12

'Place selection depending on amount of finalint
If finalint = 0 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N2")
ElseIf finalint = 1 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N3")
ElseIf finalint = 2 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N4")
ElseIf finalint = 3 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N5")
ElseIf finalint = 4 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N6")
ElseIf finalint = 5 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N7")
ElseIf finalint = 6 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N8")
ElseIf finalint = 7 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N9")
ElseIf finalint = 8 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N10")
ElseIf finalint = 9 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N11")
ElseIf finalint = 10 Then
    Selection.Copy Range("N12")
End If

End Sub
```